# How to loop through sub link by using a given URL and get a specific file in python using jupyter notebook?

Tags: python

I have to loop through this link http://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/ and further, by looping through each sub-link I have to reach finally this link http://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/2015/05/PXD000790/sdrf.tsv to get the sdrf.tsv file. But I am not able to loop through the links.

```
url='http://ftp.pride.ebi.ac.uk/pride/data/archive/'
url_data = pd.read_table(url,sep='\t')
for line in url_data:
    print(line)
```

Comment: That URL returns an HTML document. You should be using an HTML parser to extract the links.

Comment: Could you please provide me with the code? I am new to this. So, I am still learning.

Comment: You are missing many things here. You can firstly request the page using `requests` library then you can use a library to parse html page like `BeautifulSoup`. 
I can provide the code but you need to study the basics first.